# PHP: How to strip tags in a string with certain attributes that have certain values?

Tags: php

I need a function like this:

```
function strip_tags_with_attribute_values($string, $allowedTags, $allowedAttribute, $allowedValue) {

   ...

}
```

And it must produce results like this:

```
$str = '<p class="bla">hello1</p><p class='bla2'>hello2</p>';
echo strip_tags_with_attribute_values($str, '<p>', 'class', 'bla');
```

Must produce:

```
hello1<p class='bla2'>hello2</p>
```

**Why do I need this?**
Users copy and paste text from word into the FCKEditor (in Drupal). I need to strip out all the style attributes from the p and span tags.

Comment: what are your attempts in making the function?

Comment: This is going to be very hard to do - Even assuming the HTML is perfectly valid, you'll need extract a list of tags/params/values, pick the one you'll allow and stitch it all back together. You also need to consider what happens when tags are mismtached/malformed/etc. HTML is just too varied and flexible to parse reliably (I'm assuming robustness is required as this is a security mechanism of some kind?). It sounds like you've got to this problem by having a different problem elsewhere (Why allow HTML in the first place?). I suspect you won't find a decent, reliable, robust solution for this.

Comment: Users copy and paste text from word into the FCKEditor (in Drupal). I need to strip out all the style attributes from the p and span tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using something as simple as

```
$str = preg_replace("/<p class=\"(bla)\">(.+?)<\/p>/is", "$2", $str);
```

Should work. If you want arguments, you could try

```
function strip_tags_with_attribute_values($str, $tag, $att, $val)
{
    $pat = "/<{$tag} {$att}=\"{$val}\">(.+?)<\/{$tag}>/is";
    $str = preg_replace($pat, "$1", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Or something similar. This wont work correctly if a tag has multiple attributes. If that's your case, you'll probably want to try using a DOM object or XPATH to strip those out.